# Firebase and Google sign in button

Tags: firebase

Forgive me if it is basic/silly .
Using Firebase, what is the "right" way to register a new user ?

1. collect his email and pass in a banal form and manually send it to `Firebase` to create a new user ?
2. Use the `Google sign in button` and somehow connect that to Firebase ?
   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button
3. Is there an obvious way regarding Facebook ?

Comment: Is there a problem with any of these choices? Does there have to be just one right way?

Comment: Try to check if they are different and which is commonly used

Answer (score 0):

- firstly you have to add credentials of firebase to your project
- kindly go with this flow
  [google authenticate login with firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)